# How to get three matrices on the same line?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to get three different matricies on the same line, but the problem is that when I run the "code" below, I get one matrix above the other two matrices. What should I do in order to get all of them on the same line? The code is:

```
\begin{align}
     \begin{bmatrix}
           v_1^{m} \\
           v_2^m \\
           v_3^m \\
           \vdots \\
           v_n^m
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align} \[=  \left[ \begin{array}{ccccccc}
    (1-2r) & -r & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
    -r & (1-2r) & -r & . & . & . & . \\
     0 & . & . & . & . & . &. \\
     . & . & . & . & . & . & 0 \\
     . & . & . & . & -r & (1-2r) & -r \\
     0 & . & . & . & 0 & -r & (1-2r)
\end{array} \right] \times \left[ \begin{array}{c}
v_1^{m+1}\\
v_2^{m+1}\\
v_3^{m+1}\\
.\\
.\\
v_n^{m+1} 
\end{array} \right]\]
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: the reason the first matrix is above the other two is that the `align` environment and `\[...\]` each forms a separate display group.  `align` is equivalent to `equation` in this sense.  however, `align` really shouldn't be used for a one-line display.  (this isn't covered in the accepted answer, which is otherwise excellent.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? No need to mix-up arrays and matrices, and for matrix multiplication you don't need the `\times` operator. Use `amsmath`'s `bmatrix` for both vectors and the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m} \\
           v_2^m \\
           v_3^m \\
           \vdots \\
           v_n^m
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    (1-2r) & -r & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
    -r & (1-2r) & -r & . & . & . & . \\
     0 & . & . & . & . & . &. \\
     . & . & . & . & . & . & 0 \\
     . & . & . & . & -r & (1-2r) & -r \\
     0 & . & . & . & 0 & -r & (1-2r)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m+1}\\
v_2^{m+1}\\
v_3^{m+1}\\
.\\
.\\
v_n^{m+1} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Played around with some `\dots` and implemented Mico's suggestion streching the array a tiny bit to match the heights of the matrix and the vectors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m} \\
    v_2^m \\
    v_3^m \\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^m
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    (1-2r)  & -r      & 0       & \cdots  & 0  \\
    -r      & (1-2r)  & -r      & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
     0      &  \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0  \\
    \vdots  &         & -r      & (1-2r)  & -r  \\
     0      & \cdots  & 0       & -r      & (1-2r)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m+1}\\
    v_2^{m+1}\\
    v_3^{m+1}\\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^{m+1} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m} \\
    v_2^m \\
    v_3^m \\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^m
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    (1-2r)  & -r      & 0       & \cdots  & 0  \\
    -r      & (1-2r)  & -r      & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
     0      &  \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0  \\
    \vdots  &         & -r      & (1-2r)  & -r  \\
     0      & \cdots  & 0       & -r      & (1-2r)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m+1}\\
    v_2^{m+1}\\
    v_3^{m+1}\\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^{m+1} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m} \\
    v_2^m \\
    v_3^m \\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^m
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    (1-2r)  & -r      & 0       & \cdots  & 0  \\
    -r      & (1-2r)  & -r      & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
     0      &  \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0  \\
    \vdots  &         & -r      & (1-2r)  & -r  \\
     0      & \cdots  & 0       & -r      & (1-2r)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^{m+1}\\
    v_2^{m+1}\\
    v_3^{m+1}\\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^{m+1} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: I'd replace all `.` (periods) with `\cdot`, and I'd replace `\vdots` in the first column vector with `\cdot \\ \cdot`. (This comment pertains to the first version of the matrix equation.)

Comment: @Mico Why `\cdot \\ \cdot` and not `\vdots` ?

Comment: Because `\vdots` produces a row-height mismatch. Better to produce two rows, each with either `.` or `\cdot`. Incidentally, I think it would also be OK to get rid of the parentheses around `1-2r`.

Comment: @Mico Aha, I didn't know about the height mismatch. Thanks!

Comment: @Mico Any questions addressing that issue?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Mico I'm curious about the row height mismatch, and tried to find any documentation explaining what happens. Do you happen to know of any?

Comment: The row height mismatch in the first version occurs because the matrix contains two ordinary-height rows whereas the column vectors contain one row with above-average height. That's why I was recommending using `. \\ .` instead of `\vdots` in the column vectors, as doing so will even out the row heights. The mismatch in the second example occurs because `\vdots` and `\ddots` are taller than `\mathstrut` (the basic height of a row). Suggested remedy: Insert the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}` after `\begin{equation}`.